# BinaryEditor class doesn't work for PropertyGrid control in .net 6 preview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[Issue description]
After an object is selected for PropertyGrid control to display and if user attempts to click and edit any of its Byte[] property, error message shown like below and supposed BinaryEditor not brought up:

Could not find the resource
'System.ComponentModel.Design.BinaryEditorresources" among the resources "System.Windows.Forms.Design.BorderSidesEditorresources" System.ComponentMode.Design.CollectionEditor.resources" System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormatControl.resources" System.Windows.Forms.Desiqn.LinkAreaEditorresources",
System.Wingows.Forms.Desian.MaskDesignerDialog.resources" System.Wingows.Forms.Desian.ShortcutKevsEditorresources". System.SR.resources"
System.Wingows.Forms.DesignStringCo ectionEditorresources".
System.Windows.Forms.Design.Resources.System.ComponentMode.De sign.BinaryEditor.resources"
'System.Windows.Forms.Design.colordlg.data"... embedded in the
assembly "System.Windows.Forms.Design nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with anincorrect name
[image]

[Steps to reproduce]
Add a PropertyGrid control to ur WinForm.
Set the PropertyGrid.SelectedObject to an object with Byte[] type properties.
Run the Form, and click on the Byte[] type property in the PropertyGrid, u see the error message.

[.NET version Info]
Version: 6.0.400-preview.22301.10
Commit: 25580ffe7a

Host (useful for support):
Version: 6.0.6
Commit: 7cca709db2

.NET SDKs installed:
6.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.400-preview.22301.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: I see you have posted an issue related to the missing parts in the UITypeEditor implementation. Not all  UITypeEditors / Editors are yet fully implemented (most notable, the Application Property Binding editors and interfaces). - You could present the byte[] content with a [ByteViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer) object. This class is used as the presenter in the BinaryViewer editor when the `Hexadecimal` view is selected. -- You have to create it in code, since the class is decorated with `[ToolboxItem(false)]`

Comment: but how can i make any already implemented editors(including custom editors coded myself) work with the PropertyGrid control? as the default editor for byte[] property,when user clicks?

Comment: Now I get it, EditorAttribute(), a usable workaround...

Comment: Exactly. You have to build your own UITypeEditor, override `GetEditStyle()` to return `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal`, override `EditValue()`, check first whether the Type of `value` is the Type you're expecting, then cast the `IServiceProvider` object to the desired service: e.g.,  `var service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));`. if `service` is not null, create a new Form that contains your interface, including the `ByteViewer`, pass `value` (cast to the Type you're handling) to its Constructor, show it as Modal Dialog and get the result

Comment: Well, the example of a [custom UITypeEditor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor) shown in the Docs, which uses a custom Form, is a decent one, you can us it as blueprint.

Comment: As a note, there's a chance this will be fixed when the aforementioned Application Property Binding editors are also fixed, which is (loosely) scheduled to be included in an update of the current version of VS.

Comment: met a problem: Reference required for UITypeEditor to System.Drawing.dll not possible, VS suggest reference to .net framework 4.x dll but fail for sure.
Seems similar issue with: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/2413

Comment: Isn't this a WinForms app? You should already have a dependency on `System.Drawing.Common.dll` there. Or are you building a Blazor hybrid thing?

Comment: simply Winform, i am confused too.

Comment: ah, I found the problem, the model class whose properties r to be used with PropertyGrid r defined in a net standard2.0 lib, that's why. Seems i have to move it out.

Comment: Actually i found a simpler but imperfect workaround: use the TypeConverterAttribute, to convert HexStr to byte[], so user can simply type in PropertyGrid inlinely, but can't remove that "..." button.

Comment: Meh, not great. Anyway, if this is not high priority, leave it there for now; the missing resources issue related to the UITypeEditor might be fixed in the meanwhile. Otherwise, building a simple interface (given that the byte editor is already available) is not a big deal.

Comment: Haha, good news, by using EditorAttribute(string,string) constructor, i solved the imperfection finally.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround Explained**

**First Step, mark the property with either TypeConverterAttribute or EditorAttribute, or both.**

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(Hex2BinConverter)), Editor("MyWinFormApp.ByteArrayEditor, MyWinFormApp","System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Windows.Forms")]
```

**Workaround 1: A simple solution by TypeConverter:**

```
   public class Hex2BinConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string)) return true;
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string s && Utils.TryHex2Bytes(s, out byte[] bs)) return bs;  //TryHex2Bytes might be any method u wrote to convert hexstring to byte[]

            object r = null;
            try { r = base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value); }
            catch { }
            return r;
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
           CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is byte[] bs) return bs.ToHexString();  //ToHexString might be any method u wrote to convert byte[] to hexstring.
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

**Workaround 2: A simple solution by custom UITypeEditor:**

```
public class ByteArrayEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;

    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();

        if (value is byte[] bs) txtBox.Text = bs.ToHexString();

        service.DropDownControl(txtBox);

        if (Utils.TryHex2Bytes(txtBox.Text, out byte[] bs1)) value = bs1;


        return value;

    }
}
```